# Can not connect to kibana via remote connection

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have installed Kibana 5.4 and Elastic search 5.4 on a server, I'm able to access both Kibana and Elastic search via curl on the local machine using the

```
curl localhost:5601
```

I get the following response

> var hashRoute = '/app/kibana'; var defaultRoute =
>   '/app/kibana';
>
> var hash = window.location.hash; if (hash.length) {   window.location
>   = hashRoute + hash; } else {   window.location = defaultRoute; }

for Elastic search

```
curl localhost:9200
```

I get the following response

> {   "name" : "mVgeyM4",   "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
>   "cluster_uuid" : "ABV1adpCTY--e7Ib2PIBBQ",   "version" : {
>       "number" : "5.4.0",
>       "build_hash" : "780f8c4",
>       "build_date" : "2017-04-28T17:43:27.229Z",
>       "build_snapshot" : false,
>       "lucene_version" : "6.5.0"   },   "tagline" : "You Know, for Search" }

Following is my kibana.yml

```
# Kibana is served by a back end server. This setting specifies the port to use.
#server.port: 5601
# Specifies the address to which the Kibana server will bind. IP addresses and host names are both valid values.
# The default is 'localhost', which usually means remote machines will not be able to connect.
# To allow connections from remote users, set this parameter to a non-loopback address.
#server.host: "9.51.154.45:5601"
# Enables you to specify a path to mount Kibana at if you are running behind a proxy. This only affects
# the URLs generated by Kibana, your proxy is expected to remove the basePath value before forwarding requests
# to Kibana. This setting cannot end in a slash.
#server.basePath: ""
# The maximum payload size in bytes for incoming server requests.
#server.maxPayloadBytes: 1048576
# The Kibana server's name.  This is used for display purposes.
#server.name: "gtsdms.pok.ibm.com"
# The URL of the Elasticsearch instance to use for all your queries.
#elasticsearch.url: "http://localhost:9200"
# When this setting's value is true Kibana uses the hostname specified in the server.host
# setting. When the value of this setting is false, Kibana uses the hostname of the host
# that connects to this Kibana instance.
#elasticsearch.preserveHost: true
# Kibana uses an index in Elasticsearch to store saved searches, visualizations and
# dashboards. Kibana creates a new index if the index doesn't already exist.
#kibana.index: ".kibana"
# The default application to load.
#kibana.defaultAppId: "discover"
# If your Elasticsearch is protected with basic authentication, these settings provide
# the username and password that the Kibana server uses to perform maintenance on the Kibana
# index at startup. Your Kibana users still need to authenticate with Elasticsearch, which
# is proxied through the Kibana server.
#elasticsearch.username: "user"
#elasticsearch.password: "pass"
# Enables SSL and paths to the PEM-format SSL certificate and SSL key files, respectively.
# These settings enable SSL for outgoing requests from the Kibana server to the browser.
#server.ssl.enabled: false
#server.ssl.certificate: /path/to/your/server.crt
#server.ssl.key: /path/to/your/server.key
# Optional settings that provide the paths to the PEM-format SSL certificate and key files.
# These files validate that your Elasticsearch backend uses the same key files.
#elasticsearch.ssl.certificate: /path/to/your/client.crt
#elasticsearch.ssl.key: /path/to/your/client.key
# Optional setting that enables you to specify a path to the PEM file for the certificate
# authority for your Elasticsearch instance.
#elasticsearch.ssl.certificateAuthorities: [ "/path/to/your/CA.pem" ]
# To disregard the validity of SSL certificates, change this setting's value to 'none'.
#elasticsearch.ssl.verificationMode: full
# Time in milliseconds to wait for Elasticsearch to respond to pings. Defaults to the value of
# the elasticsearch.requestTimeout setting.
#elasticsearch.pingTimeout: 1500
# Time in milliseconds to wait for responses from the back end or Elasticsearch. This value
# must be a positive integer.
#elasticsearch.requestTimeout: 30000
# List of Kibana client-side headers to send to Elasticsearch. To send *no* client-side
# headers, set this value to [] (an empty list).
#elasticsearch.requestHeadersWhitelist: [ authorization ]
# Header names and values that are sent to Elasticsearch. Any custom headers cannot be overwritten
# by client-side headers, regardless of the elasticsearch.requestHeadersWhitelist configuration.
#elasticsearch.customHeaders: {}
# Time in milliseconds for Elasticsearch to wait for responses from shards. Set to 0 to disable.
#elasticsearch.shardTimeout: 0
# Time in milliseconds to wait for Elasticsearch at Kibana startup before retrying.
#elasticsearch.startupTimeout: 5000
# Specifies the path where Kibana creates the process ID file.
#pid.file: /var/run/kibana.pid
# Enables you specify a file where Kibana stores log output.
#logging.dest: stdout
# Set the value of this setting to true to suppress all logging output.
#logging.silent: false
# Set the value of this setting to true to suppress all logging output other than error messages.
#logging.quiet: false
# Set the value of this setting to true to log all events, including system usage information
# and all requests.
#logging.verbose: false
# Set the interval in milliseconds to sample system and process performance
# metrics. Minimum is 100ms. Defaults to 5000.
#ops.interval: 5000
# The default locale. This locale can be used in certain circumstances to substitute any missing
# translations.
#i18n.defaultLocale: "en"
```

But I am unable it access it on remote host either via curl or web browser, one more thing there are no errors in kibana.stderr log file of kibana. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to specify the server.host parameter in the kibana.yml file.

I have server.host: 0.0.0.0 and it works fine. I think per default it only listens to "localhost" and by binding to the loopback address it is accessible from the "outside"

Comment: I have the specified in the above config.yml I pasted above. It's the host name of the server so by 0.0.0.0, can you access it from remote host?

Comment: Your kibana.yml is empty from the view of kibana. Each entry is commented with '#'. So your kibana uses the default settings incl. the default server.host localhost. You have to add a row (or change #server.host: "9.51.154.45:5601" this line and delete the #). If you have a specified host ip, then enter it here. My elasticsearch/ kibana servers runs in a VM, so i had to add server.host: 0.0.0.0 and it becomes accessible from the host.

Comment: what are things that I must uncomment, I almost there in resolving this.

Comment: for me only uncommenting server.host entry was enough.

Comment: I had the same scenario just as you my server is running in a VM, so it worked perfectly for me. Thanks alot you saved my day!

Comment: i'm glad to help you!

Comment: @Freddy are there any other considerations I'm missing? I've followed this answer but still connection refused. I made a SO post about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47209025/cannot-access-kibana-remotely-on-ec2-instance

Answer (score 0):

The Kibana server reads properties from the kibana.yml file on startup. The default settings configure Kibana to run on localhost:5601. To change the host or port number, or connect to Elasticsearch running on a different machine, you’ll need to update your kibana.yml file. You can also enable SSL and set a variety of other options

```
elasticsearch.url:Default: "http://localhost:9200" The URL of the Elasticsearch instance to use for all your queries.
```